# Send data from Python to Javascript via network connection

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, networking, websocket

This is more a general question, I'm not asking for implementation details.

I have a Python script running on a machine which monitors an experiment and gathers live data from it. I want to visualise the data on a website and decided to go with [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/d3.js/info)

My current setup however is absolutely basic:

- The python script is running in an endless loop and appends new data
  to a text-file (`CSV` file).
- There is an `HTML`-page on the web
  server with a javascript, which grabs the file and creates a graph
  using `d3.js`.

I already thought about replacing the text-file with a `sqlite` database, but I'm sure there is a more sophisticated and easy way to do it via network.
So I am looking for a more solid solution and searched the web for different kind of strategies but most of those involve bigger libraries (`Tornado`, `node.js` etc.).

I would be happy with quite basic socket-like solution and tried to figure out how it would work with `WebSockets` but not sure how to handle this.

So my question is, what kind of design would you recommend or use if your only goal is to have a Javascript running in a browser and waiting/listening for data (let's say every few seconds a `float`), which is sent from a Python script?

Comment: why not just set an interval in javascript to make an ajax request to your python file. data returned as JSON and can be parsed in javascript.

Comment: The script is pretty complex and there are different clients attached to it, so I really want the data flow to be from Python->Website.

Comment: well with my suggestion it would be.. i currently am doing reports at my work, and the back end is python, the front end javascript. I use an ajax request to get my data from python to javascript... i have graphs that update every 30 seconds, each time its another ajax request to the database. ( i know thats pretty gross, but thats what my boss requested.. 30 seconds is a bit quick)